# VBA Worksheet_Change how to hide rows that got certain value in it

Tags: excel, vba, range, row, hide

Guys, 
can you help me with my problem.
What I need to do is to make code, that will HIDE entire row, if for example value in B10 will be = 100.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
If Range("B10").Value = 100 Then
Range("B10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: Your code could be simplified to : Range("B10").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("B10").Value2 = 100)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem.
Used this (not sure if there is anything unnecessary):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("B1:B" & LastRow) 
   If c.Value = 100 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value <> 100 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```